# c# data validation for sql datatypes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, validation

I'm writing a program that generates SQL queries to enter data into a SQL Database. All the values that should be entered into the database arrive as strings in the beginning.

But before the data can be entered / the query generated the data should be validated if it can be entered into the Database.

By reading out the Informations_Schema of the  target column I know that the data needs to be a datatype "datetime", "varchar", or "nvarchar" and so on...

Is there a way to validate a string comparing it to a SQL Server Datatype?

For example:

- Is "hello world!" a SQL Datatype "int" (error)
- Is "2017-12-12" a "datetime" (ok)
- Is "test" a "decimal" (error)

I started to write validation methods for each datatype but this seems so complicated and dirty...

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked into TRY_CONVERT? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql

Comment: You can build a method to identify the type in c# using TryParse that is a method for all numeric types.

Comment: TRY_CAST looks like a solution, alhough a solution working on the client only would even be better...

Comment: All primitive types in c# (`Int16`, `int`, `double` etc') have `TryParse` methods. `DateTime` have `TryParseExact` strings doesn't need validations at all (except maybe for null values).